# How to create menu in PyQt?

Tags: python, menu, pyqt, show

i want to create menu and if clicked go to form of menu, how to create it in PyQt ? because i'm newbie for python...
I've tried to create a menu with buttons but can not show on 2nd form and otherwise

Comment: can you be more specific.  its hard to figure out what you want, especially with the grammar.  If you create an application, the menu bar is already there.

Comment: i want create menubar n if category menu clicked go to form, how to create it ?

Comment: what category menu are you talking about.  please post screen shots of what you want to do since it is difficult to understand what you are saying

Comment: i want like http://i59.tinypic.com/2q020t5.png

Comment: Please show us a code of what you've tried